# Multi-class segmentation in Keras

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, cross-entropy

I'm trying to implement a multi-class segmentation in Keras:

- input image is grayscale (i.e 1 channel)
- ground truth image has 3 channels, each pixel is a one-hot vector of length 3
- prediction is standard U-Net trained with `categorical_crossentropy` outputting 3 channels (softmax-ed)

What is wrong with this setup? The training loss has some weird behaviour:

- in my *lucky* cases it behaves as expected (decreases)
- 90 % of the time it's stuck at ~0.9

My implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/sirfoga/attila/blob/main/attila/nn/models/unet.py#L170)

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code: if my ground truth is 1-channel (i.e 0s everywhere and 1s somewhere) and use `binary_crossentropy` + `sigmoid` as final activation I see no weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. The solution is to weight each class i.e using a weighted cross entropy loss